# How does IMEI Survives Data Reset

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, imei

NVRAM Remains in data partition. Then why IMEI is not lost after data reset?

Comment: Isn't the IMEI in /efs?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab AFAIK `/efs` is a Samsung specific partition. Never read about it for other devices (but didn't check either).

Answer (score 2):

The IMEI is the International Mobile Equipment Identification, which you MUST have to connect to the cellphone network. If you don't have an IMEI you can't call anybody.

The IMEI isn't wiped by performing a data reset because it is being held in a separate partition called /efs, modem or modemst - the Name of the partition depends on your phone's brand. That partition is not touched by the reset-option.

It happens sometimes that the IMEI is lost after a Bad flash. But I wouldn't try to force it because your phone will refuse to connect to the network. Also IMEI hacking is illegal in some countries.

Cheers

Comment: Not every device seems to have an `efs` partition, not at least my Mediatek device has.

Comment: Then it could be that it is has a different name. I think /efs is Samsung related. My Z2 also seems to have no /efs partition

Comment: So where is it in different devices...

Comment: I do not know. But it could be in some folder called modem, modemst or something similar. Since I dont worry about my IMEI i dont care where it is. Also, as I mentioned above, IMEI hacking is illegal in some countries.